# Linearity coefficient mapping to polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In this Vandermonde matrix section right at the beginning of my book, the authors comment on the linearity properties of polynomials and conclude that this must mean a mapping from polynomial coefficients to sampled polynomial values is linear. Their explanation in photo:

[image]

That seems like a large jump to me. Can someone please elaborate on how the coefficients, say, $c_0,...,c_k, \, 1 < k < n-1$ can be linearly mapped as mentioned, to a corresponding polynomial of degree $k$? Importantly, *because* of the text leading up to that conclusion.

I think I'm just overthinking this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way:
Let $p(x)=c_2x^2+c_1x+c_0$. Then we want to create a map that sends $$\mathbf{c}=\begin{bmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}p(x_1)\\p(x_2)\\p(x_3)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_0+c_1x_1+c_2x_1^2\\c_0+c_1x_2+c_2x_2^2\\c_0+c_1x_3+c_2x_3^2\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{p}.$$
But
$$\begin{bmatrix}c_0+c_1x_1+c_2x_1^2\\c_0+c_1x_2+c_2x_2^2\\c_0+c_1x_3+c_2x_3^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&x_1&x_1^2\\1&x_2&x_2^2\\1&x_3&x_3^2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c_0\\c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}.$$
So this map is simply a multiplication by (the Vandermonde) matrix, hence linear.

**Added note**

Based on your comment I think this is what you might be looking for.

Let $T$ be the map from the coefficient space to the the sampled points space. Continuing with the example above, let $q(x)=d_2x^2+d_1x+d_0$, then the map $T$ will send
$$\mathbf{d}=\begin{bmatrix}d_0\\d_1\\d_2\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}q(x_1)\\q(x_2)\\q(x_3)\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf{q}.$$
Now consider
$$T(\mathbf{c}+\mathbf{d})=\begin{bmatrix}(p+q)(x_1)\\(p+q)(x_2)\\(p+q)(x_3)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p(x_1)+q(x_1)\\p(x_2)+q(x_2)\\p(x_3)+q(x_3)\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}p(x_1)\\p(x_2)\\p(x_3)\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}q(x_1)\\q(x_2)\\q(x_3)\end{bmatrix}=T(\mathbf{c})+T(\mathbf{d}).$$
Similarly you can check that $T(\lambda \mathbf{c})=\lambda T(\mathbf{c})$. Hence the linearity is obtained based on the linearity of the polynomial space.

Comment: Thank you, I think that's (for me) an illuminating example, but it feels like the converse of what the author is stating. It seems that they're asserting that since polynomials satisfy the displayed properties then the map in question is linear.   
  
They do already state in the text, before my picture that all finite matrix multiplications are linear mappings and conversely, that linear mappings can be expressed as a matrix. So I'm expecting to be true, I just don't what the displayed examples of linearity (pictures) have to do with the author's conclusion: "Thus the map from vectors..."

Comment: I'd like to add that my tone here is respectful, and I am not in any way trying to be difficult.

Comment: @Zduff I have added some notes. Hopefully that is what you were looking for. Otherwise let me know.

Comment: Alright, got it. It seems we could have shown that any mapping between finite vector spaces, in which the resultant vector's elements are defined by some linear function, must itself be linear. Edit: linear with respect to the original, mapped vectors.